# Determinant of involutory matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, involutions

> If $A$ is an $n \times n$ involutory matrix, then show that $$\det (A) = (-1)^{n - \text{tr}(A) \over 2}$$

---

A matrix is [involutory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involutory_matrix) if it is its own inverse, $A^{-1} = A$. Thus, the eigenvalues of an involutory matrix are $\pm 1$, and its determinant is also $\pm 1$. Regarding the trace, for a given matrix of order $n$, its trace can be any integer from $-n$ to $n$. But, how to proceed?
I was wrong on thinking trace can be any interger from $-n$ to $n$ for matrix of order $n$.

Comment: Let $p$ be the multiplicity of eigenvalue $+1$. Let $n-p$ be the multiplicity of eigenvalue $-1$. Try to find the trace in terms of $n$ and $p$. Then write $p$ in terms of $n$ and the trace.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo trace will be $(2p-n)$

Comment: Now write $p$ in terms of $n$ and the trace. Note that $\det (A) = (+1)^p (-1)^{n-p}$.

Comment: $p$=$tr(A)+n \over 2$

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo i got it. thanks for your time.

Comment: When you find some time, please consider writing an answer to your own question. Comments are ephemeral.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo sure i will.